# Engine speed and flywheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

My doubt is about the third part of the question. I want to understand that if an engine is running at a constant speed, say 210 rpm, then can there be an acceleration in the flywheel? Because if the crankshaft is rotating at a given speed, then how can there be an accelerating torque on the flywheel, and if so, how the speed is constant[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @John Rennie I think the users is asking about the concept behind the third part of the question(given in the image) and not the solution to the question itself.

Comment: yes, actually it would not be clear without the image and i was asking the concept, not the solution. the solution is with me.

Comment: @MKC Did you understand the answer? How was the acceleration calculated in the solution?

Answer (score 1):

***Because if the crankshaft is rotating at a given speed, then how can there be an accelerating torque on the flywheel, and if so, how the speed is constant?***

It is because the accelerations and decelerations cause by the torques on the flywheel are small and cancel each other out during steady conditions,  so that the angular velocity of the flywheel is fairly constant. The following will explain. Refer to the Figures below.

The angular acceleration of the flywheel is governed by Newton’s second law and is given by

$$α=\frac{τ}{I}$$

Where $α$ is the angular acceleration, $τ$ is the torque applied to or by the flywheel an $I$ is the mass moment of inertia of the flywheel. It is analogous to the application of Newton’s second law to the piston, or

$$a=\frac{F}{m}$$

Where $a$ is the linear acceleration of the piston, $F$ is the net force applied to or by the piston, and $m$ is the inertial mass of the piston.

Consider the equation for angular acceleration. A flywheel has a high mass moment of inertia. It makes the flywheel ideal for storing rotational kinetic energy. It is designed to resist change in motion due to an applied torque.

Figures 1 and 5 show piston at its extremes. Here the torque on the flywheel is zero and the angular velocity, and thus kinetic energy, is at a maximum. The speed and kinetic energy of the piston, on the other hand, is zero as it is about to reverse itself.

In going from Fig 1 to 3 the torque on the flywheel is increasing and its angular acceleration is increasing negatively (it is doing work on the piston). It is loosing kinetic energy, transferring it to the piston. By the time it reaches Fig 3 the torque is a maximum and the speed, and thus the kinetic energy, of the flywheel is a minimum. The speed, and therefore kinetic energy of the piston, on the other hand, is at its maximum.

Going from Fig 3 to Fig 5 the torque decreases, and kinetic energy of the flywheel increases to reach another maximum at Fig 5. The kinetic energy of the piston is once again zero. After Fig 5 the cycle reverses.

So what we have here is the flywheel and piston exchanging kinetic energy according to the work energy principle.

***The important thing to note is that increases and decreases in kinetic energy of the flywheel are so small as a percentage of the total kinetic energy stored in the flywheel at any given time that the speed of the flywheel is essentially constant.***

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: But, if fig1 is the starting point from which the kinetic energy of the flywheel is used to do work(compress gas) and fig 5 is the ending point till which the K.E. is used then shouldnt the angular velocity reduce continuously from fig1 to fig3?

Comment: Although the deceleration of the flywheel reaches a max at fig3 and then starts decreasing, it is still decelerating the flywheel.So the angular velocity and kinetic energy at fig5 should be less than at fig 3 (since the deceleration acts till fig5).

Comment: Please explain the answer.

Comment: @Mohan That’s essentially what I said. I said from Fig 1 to Fig 3 the flywheel “.. is loosing kinetic energy, transferring it to the piston”. To say it is loosing kinetic energy is the same as saying it is losing angular velocity.

Comment: @MohanAfter Fig 3 on the way to Fig 5 would you agree that the piston is decelerating? 
Would you agree that deceleration of the piston means the force acting on the piston is in the opposite direction of its displacement? Then would you finally agree that this means the work on the piston is negative and therefore work is done on the flywheel positive and kinetic energy is transferred from the piston to the flywheel until the latter reaches a maximum again at Fig 5?

Comment: Beautiful explanation.I understood it.But in the next step if the fuel is burnt , could you explain how the process continues?(because the energy from the fuel will be added to the system).

Comment: @Mohan Good question. All of this discussion did not take into account that the flywheel, like any other mechanical device in motion, has friction. In order to keep the flywheel at constant speed those losses must be made up. Therefore, there must be a net transfer of energy from the engine to the flywheel to make up the losses. That requires a steady supply of fuel.

Comment: And could please suggest a good book or other resource to study dynamics (balancing engines,dynamic analysis of mechanisms,flywheels,etc..)?

Comment: @Mohan Wish I could, but I'm not a ME and an ME would be a better resource. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the flywheel is rotating at a constant angular velocity, there will be a torque acting on it(by the engine) to overcome the resistance against which the flywheel(the entire flywheel crank shaft assembly) rotates.In case of automobile this resistance is the friction between the components, the external load,etc..This can be observed by letting the flywheel on bearings assembly rotate freely without connecting it to the engine, it will slowly be decelerated by the resisting forces(friction in the bearings) and comes to rest.So to maintain constant angular velocity, you have to nullify the effect of the resistance by applying an external torque(by connecting the engine or motor,etc..).This torque can be calculated by using the formla  
"(power output of the engine)÷(angular velocity of flywheel)"
But I dont think there will be an angular acceleration in the flywheel when it rotaters at constant angular velocity.
 
I think the third subdivision asks the acceleration of the flywheel,when the same torque(for the rpm mentioned in the question and power of the engine given in subdivision '3') is applied on it and there is no other external resistance(like friction,external load,etc..).Here the only resistance to increasing the angular velocity is the mass moment of inertia of the flywheel.